# Why is there a dead code warning on explicit boolean test, but not on an implicit one

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, dead-code

I was wondering why the following implicit testing for boolean true produce no dead code warning, while explicit testing produces one?

For example:

```
public void noDeadCodeWarning()
{
    final boolean x = false;
    if ( x )
    {
      System.out.println("This is dead code");  // no warning
    }
}

public void hasDeadCodeWarning()
{
    final boolean x = false;
    if ( x == true )
    {
      System.out.println("This is dead code");  // yes warning
    }
}
```

I'm using eclipse mars. and Java 1.8

Comment: Java does no warning- it's a feature of the IDE.

Comment: Because the developer of eclipse choose to do so.

Comment: OK. That would explain why if I change the "if" to a "while", the unreachable code error is given in both cases.

Comment: Gonen, here's a better explanation provided [in this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119576/getting-unreachable-code-for-boolean-primitive-but-not-for-boolean-wrapper-in-wh) by Jon Skeet, also a reference link for the [reachability rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22) is provided.

Answer (score 0):

In second method the IDE evaluate the expression so it say that it is dead code but in first method you have passed Boolean value.

According to IDE if statement need Boolean value as condition so it doesn't evaluate