# Getting unreachable code for boolean primitive but not for Boolean wrapper in while loop condition

Tags: java

**Question:**

- `flag1`, `flag3` & `flag5` AFAIK at compile time itself the variable values are resolved, hence it must be giving an error.
- `flag2`, `flag4` & `Boolean.FALSE` : why do we not get a *compile time error* ?
- found 1 reference, but not exactly the same.

  [Why is there a dead code warning on explicit boolean test, but not on an implicit one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41791434/7415499)

**Code:**

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final boolean flag1 = false;

    final Boolean flag2 = Boolean.parseBoolean("false");

    final boolean flag3 = !true;

    final Boolean flag4 = 100 == 20;

    final boolean flag5 = 10 >= 20;

    while (flag1) { System.out.println("this is unreachable code with compile error"); break;  }

    while (flag5) { System.out.println("this is unreachable code with compile error"); break;  }        

    while (flag3) { System.out.println("this is unreachable code with compile error"); break;  }
    
    while (flag2) { System.out.println("this is uncreachable code without compile error"); break;  }

    while (flag4) { System.out.println("this is uncreachable code without compile error"); break;  }

    while (Boolean.FALSE) { System.out.println("this is uncreachable code without compile error"); break;  }

}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> .\com\logics\t4\_19_Tst.java:15: error: unreachable statement
>         while (flag1) { System.out.println("this is unreachable code with compile error"); break;  }
>                       ^
> .\com\logics\t4\_19_Tst.java:17: error: unreachable statement
>         while (flag5) { System.out.println("this is unreachable code with compile error"); break;  }        
>                       ^
> .\com\logics\t4\_19_Tst.java:19: error: unreachable statement
>         while (flag3) { System.out.println("this is unreachable code with compile error"); break;  }        
>                       ^
> 3 errors
> ```

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What's the question? Why the Java compiler doesn't evaluate *everything* at compile time in order to figure everything out?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, that seems to be the question. Where's the line between what the compiler does and doesn't consider an error? Good, reasonable question IMO.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [reachability rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22) have a number of places where they refer to *constant expressions* with a value of `true` or `false`.

In your code, `flag1`, `flag3` and `flag5` are all constant expressions, so their values are used in the reachability rules.

`flag2`, `flag4` and `Boolean.FALSE` are *not* constant expressions, and can't be, because the [constant expression rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) start:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a **value of primitive type or a String** that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following: [...]

`Boolean` is neither a primitive type nor is it `String`, therefore an expression of type `Boolean` will never be classified as a constant expression. (The rules could easily have been written such that it *could* be, but that's not the way it is.)